# Is it feasible for a start-up of two developers to do full automated regression testing without manual testing?

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor

Our start-up has four core members, with only 1.5 developers, consisting of the backend developer and me (the product design guy who also codes the front-end, I count as 0.5).

The backend developer wants to reach a point of full automated testing where we no longer need to do manual regression testing, so he can push code changes without needing my laborious manual testing. We're in a fast-moving start-up with crazy deadlines #startuplife.

We currently do 2-4 week Sprints, and I do 2 hrs of manual regression testing before we push live. If we do 100% automated testing, we no longer need Sprints as he can push code continuously, after running the regression suite.

Is it feasible to aim for that level of test coverage at this point in the company? We're using AngularJS + Protractor. I would be in charge of the maintenance of these scripts, if not also the initial writing of them (we may contract it out to freelancers).

From what I've heard, automated testing eats up so much time both in writing the scripts and then maintaining the fast-growing suite. I fear it will eat up all my time that is needed for product design, etc.

Is this level of automated regression scripts too ambitious for a company of our resources?

Comment: No offense, but if your business is planning to take serious recommendations for operations from a random post on a website, you have far more serious problems than having limited developer resources.  Aside from that, this isn't even the kind of question that is appropriate to address here.

Comment: You can't reach 100% automated testing, never. Tests never cover everything. You can't push code to users without someone looking at it and verifying nothing has broken. Even testing tools can fail and you will think that all tests are passing but the app won't even start. Also, the closer you are getting to 100%, or even to 90%, the more time you will spend writing the tests (and more expensive it will be).

Comment: I've heard that writing unit, integration and functional tests can eat up to 50% again of your original dev time. I don't know if I would put it that high, but nevertheless I do think that automated testing is very useful. Consider testing either the most critical parts, the most complicated parts, or the parts that are least subject to future change. Even a low level of coverage, added into your automated build/deployment process, is valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is highly opinionated, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

From what you have described, seems you are "holding it wrong" in many ways.

1. Your sprints are too long.
2. You should be pushing to production once a day and should not be doing 2 hour of "regression testing" before every push.
3. I don't think you should strive for a full automated test suite, full test coverage is not something that a startup needs to strive for in most cases, you should cover business cases and most common workflow for your users.

Having automated tests does not remove the need for sprints, you most likely will still work in sprints but you will be able to deploy more often.

Here's a **very** common workflow

1. You have a master branch
2. You create branches for feature/bugs/hotfixes ([read more on gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) )
3. You create a PR on github that requests to be merged to master
4. Tests are running on your branch, and flagged as either passing or failing. if it's passing you merge and deploy. Solution that can help here are [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/) and many others.
5. Once you deploy, you can run what you call "regression" using [uTest](http://www.utest.com/) or some other automated service.

The key takeaways for you should be

1. Move fast
2. Ship often and early
3. Run tests automatically and as close to the change as possible

I really just scratched the surface here, hope this helps.